# Unable to set the Entry box to correct position in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to learn creating GUI using Tkinter .I created a window which includes text,Messagebox,Entry widget,labels and Radio buttons.

I used grid method for frames and tried to make entry boxes in row0 and row1 .And a message Box with Some text.But these are not properly aligned even though i gave correct rows and columns but output is not in order.

Entry box is created very far though i mentioned column1 .And message box is created as per the column specified.Can anyone help me how to solve this.If i am missing anything please let me now .

```
from Tkinter import*
import tkMessageBox


class Example:
    def __init__(self,root):
        root.title("Sample")
        #Entry functions ---------------------------------------
        Label(root, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
        Label(root, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.bind("<Return>",self.ShowChoice_radio)
        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.bind("<Return>",self.ShowChoice_radio)
        self.e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row =1,column = 1)
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.frame=Frame(root)
        self.frame.grid(row=3,sticky=W)
        self.label=Label(self.frame, text="mine", width=12,bg="green",fg="white",justify=LEFT)

        self.label.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W,pady=4)
        root.minsize(width=666, height=220)
        self.v=IntVar()
        role=[("ENGLISH",1),("SPANISH",2),("GERMAN",3)]
        Label(self.frame,text="Choose your role of target:",justify=LEFT,padx=2,pady=2).grid(row=4,sticky=W)
        i=0
        for txt,val in role:
            i=i+1
            self.rad_bt=Radiobutton(self.frame,text=txt,padx=20,variable=self.v,
                        command=self.ShowChoice_radio,value=val)
            self.rad_bt.grid(row=4,column=i+1)

        self.bottomframe = Frame(root)
        self.bottomframe.grid(row=12,sticky=W)
        self.hello(12)
        T=Text(self.bottomframe,height=2,width=30)
        T.pack(padx=100,side=TOP)
        T.insert(END,"just a normal text to display!\n")
        self.mbutton=Button(self.bottomframe,text='Quit',command=self.callback,state='normal')
        self.mbutton.pack(padx=3,pady=3,side='left')
        self.help=Button(self.bottomframe,text='Help',command=self.help_msg,width=5,justify=CENTER)
        self.help.pack(padx=93,pady=3,side='left')

    def ShowChoice_radio(self):
        print self.v.get()

    def help_msg(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Help to print ",message="Not yet implemented")
        root.minsize(width=666, height=666)
        self.show_entry_fields()
        self.help.config(state=DISABLED)
    def callback(self):
        if tkMessageBox.askyesno('verify','Really Quit?'):
            root.destroy()

    def hello(self,name):
        w=Label(root,text="Hello Tkinter!",width=15).grid(row=10)

        whatever_you_do = "Whatever . it is my test that \n i can anble to display manner  in this case find out whether it is correct one or wrong \n)"
        msg=Message(root, anchor='s',width=200,text = whatever_you_do)
        msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 14, 'italic'))
        msg.grid(row=10,column=1,sticky=W)
    def show_entry_fields(self):
       print "First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (self.e1.get(), self.e2.get())



if __name__=="__main__":
    root=Tk()
    app=Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Even the quit and Help buttons are not proper...!!!

Comment: Could you post some image or ascii art how the UI is _supposed_ to look instead?

Comment: Comment edited into answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I initially voted to close this because there is not a clear question, but mostly only a series of statements and opinions, at least one of which is incorrect. After looking more, I think I can answer your implied question "Why is tkinter behaving in a way that seems wrong to me?". The answer, I believe, is that you do not understand that grid coordinates are independent (start over) for each container gridded. Also, coordinates not used are ignored. In particular:

Root has a grid of 5 rows and 2 columns. Renumbering the rows  0, 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of the confusing labeling you used, there is no entry in column 1 for rows 2 and 4.  The width of column 0 is determined by the width of self.frame in row 2, column 0. The entry boxes are far to the right because column 0 is very wide.

Self.frame has a grid of 2 rows and 4 columns.  The first 3 columns of row 0 are empty. Self.bottomframe is packed instead of gridded.  The buttons are to the left of where you want because you packed them to the left.  In other words, tkinter did just what you said, which is apparently not what you want.

You might list the result better if you got rid of self.frame, put 'mine' in (2,0) or (2,0), 'Choose...' in  (3, 0), and a frame with 3 radio buttoms in (3,1).  Then root column 0 would not be so overly wide.

Comment: First name  ---------------

Comment: Second name -------------

Comment: Choose any one : 1. 2. 3.   ----->All are radio buttons-

Comment: choose any item:   1.                                                                                                                  2.   these nare check boxes

Comment: quit       Help                                                These two must be at bottom  center aligned

Comment: I tried to upload the image but it is not uploading properly that's why i kept comment by comment to help you to understand the layout of my GUI I want to create...